# Installshield Development Error during the Installation process

Tags: installation, project, installshield

I've been stuck by a problem for the past couple days that makes no sense to me. My installer builds fine in the Installshiled IDE but when it is about to finish the installation, int gets two errors then rollbacks: installation failure.

Right when the install bar is at about 100%, an error box pops up that states this:
"Error 1001.Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)."

The box pops up once, then the installer flashes its status to "rollback" then pops up another error box, then once 'ok'ed it procedes to rollback as usual.

I don't understand that error message so i looked in the msi loggings and found this:

> InstallShield 13:20:08: Initializing Property Bag...
>   InstallShield 13:20:08: Getting file count from property bag
>   InstallShield 13:20:08: File Count : 7
>   InstallShield 13:20:08: Sorting Based On Order...
>   InstallShield 13:20:08: This setup is running on a 32-bit Windows...No need to load ISBEW64.exe
>   InstallShield 13:20:08: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\QMWSChartDataServer.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\DataDelivery.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\QMGlobalData.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\QMAdoDB.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\QMPatientData.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\MedShareGlobalData.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Registering file C:\Program Files\Cadwell\Easy III\MedDirectory.dll (32-bit)
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Begin Comitting Property Bag
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Write KeyList count
>   InstallShield 13:20:09: Finished Comitting Property Bag
>   Action 13:20:09: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.commit. 
>   Action 13:20:09: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.rollback. 
>   Action 13:20:09: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.install.
>
> Error 1001.Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019).
>
> MSI (s) (34!84) [13:20:26:455]: 
>   Info 2769.Custom Action _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
>   Action ended 13:20:26: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
>   Action 13:20:26: Rollback. Rolling back action:
>   Rollback: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.install
>   Rollback: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.rollback
>
> Error 1001.Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019).
>
> MSI (s) (34!E8) [13:20:27:036]: 
>   Info 2769.Custom Action _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.rollback did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
>   Rollback: _EBDE7916DF6AF3B644016C54F66930DC.commit
>   Rollback: ISSelfRegisterFiles
>   Rollback: Registering modules
>   Rollback: Registering type libraries
>   Rollback: Writing system registry values
>   Rollback: Registering program identifiers

All rollbacking commands after this point.

For some reason it looks like to me that installshield is trying to launch my program before it finishes the installation, even when I told it to prompt the user to decide to launch. 
Is this a registering command system that makes it attemp or what? I've been scouring the web all day and I've found some ideas, but I havent seen any solutions as of yet.

The installers that I've tried(and failed) have always needed to be Setup.exes, when i try to build a .msi only setup I get this error message. It may help someone who knows more about this system than I do.

Your project contains InstallShield prerequisites. A Setup.exe setup launcher is required if you are build a release that includes InstallShield prerequisites. Change your release settings to build Setup.exe, or remove the prerequisites from your project. 
-7076
There's nothing on the site that has anything from the error code, so I'm at a loss.

System:
XP SP3
Installshield 2010 Pro
Install being tested on a VirtualPC

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning what kind of application you're trying to install, but you might find [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/627ee1ab-3edd-45a2-9b4e-22883b8e500f) on Microsoft forums useful as analogous symptoms are discussed there.